# Передается указатель вместо копии

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
struct object
{
    std::string name, 
                type = "string", 
                value;
    object() {}
    object(std::string name, std::string value="", std::string type="string")
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->type = type;
        this->value = value;
    }
    object& operator=(std::string _Val)
    {
        value = _Val;
        return (*this);
    }
};
struct Form
{
    uint32_t size;
    object * objects;
    Form() {}
    Form(object objects[], uint32_t size)
    {
        this->size = size;
        this->objects = objects;
    }
};
class Data
{
    uint32_t sizeVal;
public:
    object *objects;
    uint32_t size()
    {return sizeVal;}
    Data(object objects[], uint32_t size)
    {
        this->sizeVal = size;
        this->objects = objects;
    }
    Data(Form form)
    {
        objects = form.objects;
        sizeVal = form.size;
    }
    Data(){}
    ERROR_ID SetValueByID(ID id, std::string value)
    {
        if (id >= sizeVal) return -1;
        objects[id].value = value;
        return 0;
    }
    ERROR_ID SetValueByName(std::string name, std::string value)
    {
        int id = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeVal; i++)
        {
            if (objects[i].name == name)
            {
                id = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (id == -1) return -1;
        objects[id].value = value;
        return 0;
    }
    object& getObjByID(ID id)
    {
        if (id >= sizeVal)
        {
            object error_value;
            return error_value;
        }
        return objects[id];
    }   
    object& getObjByName(std::string name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeVal; i++)
        {
            if (objects[i].name == name) return objects[i];
        }
        object error_value;
        return error_value;
    }
};



object x[5] = {object("name"), object("password"), object("secretask"), object("123"), object("124")};
    Form form(x,5);
    DataBase DB(form, "newdb");
    Data user(x, 5), user2(x,5), user3(x, 5);
```

Почему адрес objects у form, user,user2,user3 одинаковый?
И как это исправить?

Comment: Ну, вы же просто копируете указатель. Может вам вместо него больше подойдет `std::vector`?

Comment: Вы передаёте аргументом массив `object` этот массив в конструкторе и фиксируется. Это `&x` или `&x[0]` что одно и то же.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, размер должен быть фиксированным.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, и как передать копию массива, вместо него самого?

Comment: @Alleksh_ Это не мешает использовать вектор. Можете еще попробовать `std::array`, но размер тогда должен быть известен на этапе компиляции.

Comment: да тут рассадник чудо кода. К примеру, функция getObjByID может возвратить ссылку на локальный объект (что уже UB),  А также передавать массив и размер, если есть vector...